# Kafka - to - HDFS / Connect-Avro-Standalone.properties

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, hdfs, apache-kafka-connect

I want to connect and move log file kafka to hdfs as .avro file. But i havent decided that which converter is should used. How can i organize this file ?

**confluent-3.2.1 /etc/schema-registry/connect-avro-standalone.properties**

```
bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092

key.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
key.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081


value.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
value.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081


internal.key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter

internal.key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
internal.value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter

internal.key.converter.schemas.enable=true
internal.value.converter.schemas.enable=true
```

Comment: Your question is difficult to understand. Do you need help deciding the converter? What do you mean by "organize this file"?